# Hudson - job is stuck, how to kill it?

Tags: hudson

I have a job running under Hudson that has not progressed from "Started by user anonymous". How can I stop it? I tried restarting the Hudson server but it just resumed the job on startup.

It can't be killed by the normal cancel build button.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a corresponding job on the box that can be killed?  For example, a maven or ant process?

Comment: Odd. If you kill the Hudson server, you should be able to identify whether the offending process is still running (via Task Manager or `ps`). Is this not the case? What kind of job are you running?

Comment: Doesn't get as far as invoking a build script I know about - this is before it even checks anything out of SVN.

Comment: On second thoughts it might be waiting for a response from SVN that will never come - the URL it is currently pointing to isn't valid but is a repository.

Comment: Interesting little bug this one but Hudson was hung waiting for SVN because I didn't at that time have permission to that repository and it was my id I was using for Hudson. After getting my permissions updated Hudson kicked back into life - and the job canceled almost immediately afterwards. So presumably I would have needed to kill an SVN process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hudson was waiting for SVN to respond - SVN was waiting for the permission for my id to use the repository. Once this was there Hudson started working again.

I would presume that in this instance there would have been an SVN process I would have needed to kill in order to get Hudson to respond again.

Answer (score 2):

Check your build process to make sure that it's not waiting for interactive input.  For example, if you run over ssh, and the server isn't in the known hosts file, maybe it's waiting for you to authorize the fingerprint.  Likewise, if you haven't setup automatic key exchange, maybe it's waiting for you to enter a password.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where the job was stuck at its early stage. I did the following and got it to work. Not sure what exactly did the trick.

1. ssh to the build node, which the job is attached to and clean its workspace
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/hudson restart` to restart the service on the Hudson server.
3. re-enter the source code credentials
4. start the build job